# VCL event during destruction

Tags: delegates, destructor, c++builder, vcl

I'm having a problem where certain VCL controls occasionally fire off events while being destroyed, causing handlers to be invoked in a sub-classed form which has already been destroyed (e.g. the control gets killed by the destructor of a parent of the TForm.)

Is this a breach-of-contract by the (third-party) control in question, am I supposed to litter every event handler with "if(open)" guards, or should this be taken care of by some other mechanism. I had, perhaps naively, just assumed that that __published closures would have been unregistered automatically, somewhat akin to how regular virtual functions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__published` closures do not make any assurance of that kind, a closure is simply a pointer to a class instance and a function within. However there are other mechanics in the VCL that does.

Normally it is good practice when developing components that are dependent on other components, to make sure to clear any internal reference to a component when it is deleted. In the VCL one can achieve this through the free notifications in `TComponent`.

If the component you rely on, have a different owner and is not on the form, then you have to register your component to receive these notifications. You do this through the [`FreeNotification`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TComponent.FreeNotification) function (remember to unregister your component again when you are deleting the notified component, for this use [`RemoveFreeNotification`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TComponent.RemoveFreeNotification)). Whenever a control is added to the same form (or owner) as this component the function [`Notification`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TComponent.Notification) will be called with a reference to the component added or removed and the action performed.

So you simply overwrite the `Notification` function, remember to call the parent's function as well. The overloaded function could look like this:

```
void __fastcall TMyComponent::Notification(TComponent* AComponent, TOperation Operation)
{
    if (Operation == opRemove && AComponent == interestingComponent)
    {
        this->interestingComponent = NULL;
    }

    inherited::Notification(AComponent, Operation);
}
```

If this is a third party control they should of course ensure this and make sure that there are [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), due to a component being freed, if they for some reason forgot you would have to add that functionality, either by subclassing or by resetting events as you stated. If this is your own component then you should do make sure to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you buggy controls have their "Owner" property set correctly? By default, a form owns all controls that are on it, which have their "Owner" property point to TForm instance, and this form is responsible for freeing all owned controls. That is the way how stuff works if you design your forms via IDE Form designer. If you create controls manually, you must provide "Owner" property through constructor. Check if you pass correct Form as an "Owner". Also, if you have sources of your custom-controls, built on a top of TControl, check if their constructor correctly pass "Owner" property to the underlying TControl constructor.

Comment: Yes, this was all automatically created by the designed and the Owner property points to the Form both during executing and as well as during the crash.

For the record the component seems to get destroyed at the expected time. ~TWinControl apparently walks through and kills all owned components. The problematic control's destructor then tries to deliver an event to our form, which has already been destroyed and of which there's only some parent classes left at that point.

Comment: Why are you firing events in the destructor?  In any case, you can simply check the `ComponentState` property for the `csDestroying` flag before calling an event handler.